# Is this PDE system related to any known equations from relativistic quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, klein-gordon-equation

The system of equations I obtained looks like this:

> $$\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 w }{\partial t^2}=\Delta w-\nabla \vec{\varphi}$$
>
> $$\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \vec{\varphi} }{\partial t^2}=\left( \frac{mc}{\hbar} \right)^2 (\nabla w-\vec{\varphi} )+\alpha^2 \left(\Delta \vec{\varphi}+\beta \nabla (\nabla \vec{\varphi}) \right)$$

We have one scalar and one vector function:

$$w=w(x,y,z,t)$$

$$\vec{\varphi}=\vec{\varphi}(x,y,z,t)=\varphi_x\vec{e_x}+\varphi_y\vec{e_y}+\varphi_z\vec{e_z}$$

If we take $\alpha=0$, the last three equations become decoupled and we can obtain a simple Klein-Gordon equation.

> Is this system of equations related to some known relativistic quantum mechanics equations?

---

I have derived this system of equations, using methods of [plate theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindlin%E2%80%93Reissner_plate_theory#Governing_equations), but for a '3D plate' in 4D space, and replacing the medium parameters with the appropriate quantities from quantum mechanics.

For example, the 'thickness of the plate' is the reduced Compton wavelength $\frac{\hbar}{mc}$, while $c$ is the speed of the transverse waves in the 'medium'. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the 'left-over' free parameters, which are related to the 'Poisson ratio of the medium'.

Comment: Your equations (as you probably already know) are not Lorentz-invariant.

Comment: Question about notation: what is $\Delta w$?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus, yes, I know (in the case of $\alpha \neq 0$). Which probably means, they can't be relativistic, right? I didn't think about that

Comment: @flippiefanus, $$\Delta w=\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial z^2}$$ I thought it was common notation

Comment: Even if $\alpha = 0$ the first equation is not Lorentz invariant. Not necessarily so (about the system being nonrelativistic): it can still describe a relativistic field in the stationary medium. But it can't be something fundamental, like a theory of elementary particles.